# How to use import pod in iOS app when given source code

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I've had this really long-standing question regarding CocoaPods and dependencies that give you source code instead of a compiled binary (e.g. Bolts, FSBSDK*Kit, etc.).

Here is my Podfile for reference:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'stand' do
    pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
end
```

But when I go looking for the FBSDKCoreKit.framework compiled binary, I don't see it. I see this:

[image: FB SDK Source]

How am I supposed to import this as a dependency? Here are all the linked frameworks and libraries I have:

[image: XCode Linked Frameworks and Libraries]

I usually solve this problem by cloning the repo and building the code manually, but this seems like it defeats the purpose of using CocoaPods.

p.s. Sorry if this is a duplicate question. Couldn't really put the problem into a search term that yielded results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you open the new `.xcworkspace` file and not the `.xcodeproj` you created. When you'll build your project, *Cocoapods* will compile the files and build the library for you to use. No need to add manually frameworks in **Linked Frameworks and Librairies** of the **General** tab.

It should look like this:
[image: Exemple of basic cocoapod workspace]

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was just missing that step. I did `pod update` and it resolved the builds errors when compiling Bolts.